# Difference between MSMQ and Service Bus for Windows Server

Tags: .net, msmq, windows-server-2012

I am doing r&d for migrating MSMQ to Service Bus for Windows Server(on-premise window 2012 server)

I want to know the solid reasons(advantages) to use Service Bus instead of MSMQ. But I have got some limitations(size limit and some dependencies.) of Service Bus rather than advantages.

Thanks
mit

Answer (score 2):

MSMQ is just a raw message transport service. A queue is basically a fifo, you push message on it and in the other you peek or pop the message. Service Bus offer the service of an enterprise service bus, so you can have a more high level API, providing for example Topic based publication/subscriptions, and other typical ESB facilities. So it depends, if you have an application already running with raw MSMQ there is no reason in my opinion to add an extra cost to move to Service Bus, since you will not add any benefit. If you are writing a brand new application, you would probably consider to have it as a part of your infrastructure.